# extract UID from /etc/passwd using RegEx

Tags: regex, extract, text-extraction, uid, passwd

I would like to extract UID from /etc/passwd file which looks like this-

```
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/bin/sh
```

The problem I'm facing is that even if I match first 33, the second 33 (GID) is also getting matched. How I match first occurrence only?

So far I've this- `[\d]+`

Comment: Can you limit your regex matcher to one match only?

Comment: What regex are you currently using?

Comment: updated with what I've right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a possessive-quantifier:

Try

```
[\d]+?
```

Answer (score 0):

That `x` in the second field used to contain the crypted password. Nowadays you can pretty much be sure that it is `x` for all entries so you can use the following:

```
$ grep x:33 /etc/passwd
```

See [shadow password](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_password) for details on that `x`.

You didn't tell us what you were trying to do actually so I'll take a guess that you might want to look at the `man id` man page.

If it's only uid that you're interested in then you can use `cut`:

```
$ cut -f 3 -d: /etc/passwd
```

Comment: I am trying to extract UID from /etc/passwd file